# How to make Google Chrome Frame support ActiveX plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, activex

My customers still use Windows XP as their OS on which the newest version of IE is version 8. IE 8 does not support most of HTML5 features which are used in my software.
So I want to use `Google Chrome Frame` to solve this problem.

On the other hand my software also need to embed an ActiveX plugin to render sense which might not be supported by `Google Chrome Frame`. I know a extension named `ActiveX for Chrome` can make chrome support ActiveX plugins. I tested in the original google chrome, it works. But I do not know how to install `ActiveX for Chrome` extension to `Google Chrome Frame`.

Any reply will be thankful.

> 1. [ActiveX for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/activex-for-chrome/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn)
> 2. [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

After google some web pages, I found the answer.

1. Enter `gcf:about:version` in IE.
2. right click the menu.
3. select `review element menu item`.
4. click the system icon of the popup window.
5. click new windows menu item.

Then you got a chrome window. Install the ActiveX for Chrome.